# Permission error when trying to download dropbox folder via python

Tags: python, dropbox

I am using dropbox library in a python script(python 3.7.3) and trying to download a .zip file via shared link.

However I am receiving **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/dnload/'**. The folder is created, the permissions are set via right-click properties for every usergroup but still cannot download the folder, tried also chmod with different modes, tried running as administrator the pycharm and without any luck.

Anyone has any idea how can I get rid of this error?

This is the part of code used:

```
@staticmethod
def try_download():

    var_1 = os.access("C:/dnload/", os.X_OK | os.W_OK)
    var_2 = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file_to_file(download_path="C:/dnload/", url="url/hola.zip?dl=1", link_password="password")
```

P.S: Tried also with dl=0 and the same error arise.

Comment: Try following python script : `f = open("C:/dnload/file.txt", "w"); f.write("data"); f.close()`, and tell if it produces same error

Comment: @Programmer, no. I found the problem, which was that I gave in the download_path a folder path and not included also a filename.
Thanks